# Which TextEditor is easiest to customize for a new scripting language?

Tags: ide, scripting

It's been more than an year that i'm developing a new scripting language with its own grammar rules and constructs.
I'd like to give the users of this language some minimalistic ide to work with, but i don't want/have time to make one from scratch so i'd like to take one already existing (it has to run on Linux platforms natively, so no windows-only editors plz) and customize it.

Well, which one is the easiest to customize without changing the source code and recompiling it, maybe even with plugin support?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I don't need to know which editor is the best for you, i need to know which one is the easiest to customize AND, most of it, **which one has the most complete documentation about new language customization**.

*Ex: SciTE is good, but its documentation about custom grammars is really poor.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a very ambitious project and I wish you luck.

I don't use linux too often, I use a Mac and my favorite text editor is called [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) because it has snippets, code completion, and a whole mess of other features. The closest thing to it that I've found on linux is called [Scribes](http://scribes.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: +1 'cause i didn't know that and i like it, but (quote from the site) :

" No, Scribes will not support multiple document interfaces.

Scribes is just a single component of GNOME that focuses exclusively on text processing and manipulation. Other components for GNOME need to be, or have been, developed that focus on other specialized tasks. With enough specialized components, GNOME becomes a development environment for artists, developers, administrators, students, engineers etc. "

I need tabbing :(

Comment: found a guide on how to customize it, really REALLY nice! tnx

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [Scintilla/SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/)? I think it gets used often for this sort of thing. It's very lightweight, but from what I understand, is easy to add functionality to. It's not really an IDE, but it's more of a text-editor component that you could use as the basis for a simple IDE. I've used SciTE, which is a sort of demo text editor of Scintilla's capabilities. It's simple, but also quite fast and responsive.

I suppose another option would be to write plugins for existing IDEs such as [Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Plug-in_Development_FAQ) or [Netbeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroNetBeansPluginDev). Both of these IDEs support many languages just through 3rd-party plugins. Going this route means you don't need to build a complete UI, just the components needed to make your language work.

The downside of building plugins for an extendable IDE (such as NetBeans or Eclipse) is that you are at the mercy of the IDE developers. If they change the way the platform works, you must ensure that your plugins still work with the new versions. Sometimes this can become a major problem.

All of these options should work on Linux as well as Windows.

Comment: I had problems with SciTE ... i've created the properties and api files but they didn't seem to work ... there's no documentation about language customizing for scite :(

Answer (score 0):

There's always Emacs or Vim (I lean towards Vim, but that's just my opinion :) ). Neither are IDEs *per se*, but both are very extensible and it shouldn't be too hard to create settings for each that will aid people writing scripts in your language.

Comment: I like vim too but nowdays few people use vim or emacs to code (and it's a shame indeed).

Comment: Few people? I don't mean to be contradictory (especially with nothing but anecdotal evidence), but most of the Linux/Unix programmers I know, and even a fair number of Mac programmers, continue to use Emacs or Vim. I suppose not many Windows-bound programmers use Emacs or Vim, but...